# Does a Trigger.io reload delete all locally saved files?

Tags: reload, trigger.io

The [docs](https://trigger.io/modules/file/current/docs/index.html) say that `forge.file.saveURL()` saves a file in "a permanent location", but when I perform a reload on my app and restart it, all the files that were previously downloaded and saved locally are downloaded again.

What actually happens to the local file store on reload, and is there a way to persist files? I'd like to be able to update and reload a line of JS without forcing the user to redownload megabytes of image and audio files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to recreate any saveURL problems with Reload - what I did:

- create a new app
- use `file.saveURL` and `prefs` module to download a file and remember its location (https://gist.github.com/goodgravy/6539470)
- run the app - image is shown in app
- make a small change to the app (e.g. some text in index.html)
- push out Reload update
- switch away from app, wait for Reload to be downloaded, switch back to app
- index.html change has been made, and image is still shown from original saved location

I tried that out on Android 4.2 and iOS 7.

Could you try that stripped-down app I linked to to see if you're seeing the same thing? If it *is* still a problem, please let us know what device and OS version you're on there.